# MobileFirst: How to pass parameters to adaptor using angularJS

Tags: angularjs, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using angularJS in Mobile first and i am getting error as parameter values are not recevied by adaptor

need to know how to pass parameters in `function(function($scope.userName, $scope.password)) & parameter(parameters : [$scope.userName, $scope.password])` variable using `$scope` or without `$scope`

```
app.controller('loginController',function($scope){

    $scope.login = function($scope.userName, $scope.password){
        $scope.userNameTxt = angular.element('#usrName').val();
        $scope.passwordTxt = angular.element('#pass').val();
        console.log($scope.userName, $scope.password);
        $scope.userName = $scope.userNameTxt;
        $scope.password =$scope.passwordTxt;
        $scope.loginProcedure = {
                procedure : 'login',
                adaptor : 'SQL',
                parameters : [$scope.userName, $scope.password]
        };

        WL.Client.invokeProcedure($scope.loginProcedure,{
            onSuccess : $scope.loginSuccess,
            onFailure : $scope.loginFailure
        });

        $scope.loginSuccess = function(data)
        {
            $scope.data = data;
            console.log($scope.data);
        };

        $scope.loginFailure = function()
        {
            console.log('failed');
        };
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Two-way binding**

If you are using two-way binding in your controller as shown below

```
<div ng-controller="loginController">
  <form ng-submit="login()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="username" placeholder="Username" />
    <input type="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password" />

    <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login"  />
  </form>
</div>
```

then you can use the following:

```
app.controller('loginController',function($scope){

    $scope.login = function(){
        $scope.loginProcedure = {
                procedure : 'login',
                adapter : 'SQL',
                parameters : [$scope.username, $scope.password]
        };

        WL.Client.invokeProcedure($scope.loginProcedure,{
            onSuccess : $scope.loginSuccess,
            onFailure : $scope.loginFailure
        });

        $scope.loginSuccess = function(data)
        {
            $scope.data = data;
            console.log($scope.data);
        };

        $scope.loginFailure = function()
        {
            console.log('failed');
        };
    }
});
```

**No binding:**

If you are not using two-way binding for your form fields then you could try the following:

```
app.controller('loginController',function($scope){

    $scope.login = function(){
        var username = angular.element('#usrName').val();
        var password = angular.element('#pass').val();

        $scope.loginProcedure = {
                procedure : 'login',
                adapter : 'SQL',
                parameters : [username, password]
        };

        WL.Client.invokeProcedure($scope.loginProcedure,{
            onSuccess : $scope.loginSuccess,
            onFailure : $scope.loginFailure
        });

        $scope.loginSuccess = function(data)
        {
            $scope.data = data;
            console.log($scope.data);
        };

        $scope.loginFailure = function()
        {
            console.log('failed');
        };
    }

});
```

Comment: this works for me but is there a way using $scope? as its angularJS environment

Comment: @WorklightBeginner check the update to the answer and if that works could you please mark the answer as correct?

Comment: got error as "[/AngularBootStrap/apps/services/api/AB/common/query] failure. state: 500, response: Missing Json Query Parameter adapter"

Comment: Two-way binding do nothing ... no event

Comment: @WorklightBeginner since we are binding the the `$scope` variable we don't need to alias the controller. I've updated the view and that's the only thing you need to update

Comment: @WorklightBeginner if the answer helped to resolve your issue could you mark it as correct

Comment: when i click login button for first time it wont class a $scope.loginSuccess function .... when i click second time it gets called

Comment: @WorklightBeginner the `loginSuccess` function will only be invoked when the adapter call completes successfully. If the success function is not being called then there was a problem with the adapter invocation and that is a separate issue from the original question. If the question **How to pass parameters to adaptor using angularJS** was answered then could you mark the question as correct so that we can move on to other questions

Comment: Your answer didn't solved my issue ... i got solution from other source and the solution was spelling mistake 'adaptor' which is present in both your and my code ... its actually 'adapter'

Comment: @WorklightBeginner the property in indeed 'adapter'. We are not here to verify every single word in your code. The reason why `adaptor` is found in my code snipped it because I used your code snippet. The question was how to pass parameters (username and password) to the login function and that was address by my answer. Since you had `adaptor` in your code then the adapter invocation will not work the 1st time nor the 100th time therefore your previous statement that it worked the second time was incorrect.

Comment: @WorklightBeginner if you don't mark the answer as correct or post "your solution" then that defeats the purpose. Stackoverflow is used by millions of people and therefore it's good practice to acknowledge when an answer is correct so other benefit as well. PS: I just updated the answer to reflect the misspelling of the property